# Como passar/receber dados para os componentes através do routing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routes

No meu app-routing-module eu vou reutilizar o mesmo componente para quatro rotas diferentes, porém preciso saber uma forma de diferenciar esses componentes.

Atualmente meu app-routing passa uma propriedade title no data:

```
  {
    path: 'x',
    loadChildren:'./pages/x/x-x/x-x.module#xModule',
    data: {
      title: 'x'
    }
  }
```

Como eu recupero esse valor no meu componente para fazer a lógica que preciso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

No meu **app-routing.module**:

```
{
    path: 'xxx',
    loadChildren:'./pages/xxx/xxx-xxx/xxx-xxx.module#xxxModule',
    data: {
      title: 'Título que vou passar'
    }
}
```

No meu **componente**:

```
public rotaAtual: Subscription;

constructor(
public route: ActivatedRoute){}

public getTitulo(): void {
    this.rotaAtual = this.route.data.subscribe((res) => {console.log(res)}
)}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.rotaAtual.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

ngOnInit(){
  let lastRoute=this.route;
  while(lastRoute.firstChild){
   lastRoute=firstChild
  }
  this.lastRoute.data.subscribe(data=>console.log(data)
 }
}
```

Comment: Você está pegando os dados pela URL?

Comment: Não é pela url, é pela propriedade data da rota

Comment: E como fica o código no arquivo routing? Como ele recebe e envia os valores?

Comment: fica o igual da pergunta por exemplo. Os valores são estaticos.

Comment: Fiz algo parecido, vou adicionar minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

A forma que nosso amigo Edward mostrou é com parametros na rota, você também consegue passar query parametros que acredito ser da forma que você deseja obter.

Pelo seu exemplo não ficou claro em qual momento você vai mudar de uma rota para outra, mas vou dar meu exemplo que seria um click em uma tag de ancora, ficaria assim:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/rotaUtilizada']" [queryParams]="data:{title: 'Título que vou passar'}">
  Clique Aqui
</a>
```

Desta forma através do seu this.router você consegue pegar o parâmetro passado. A sua URL irá ficar desta forma: rotautilizada?data="Titulo que passou".

Se quiser passar query parameter pelo ts é só fazer como o exmeplo que nosso amigo deu passando a propriedade queryParams.

Nete artigo explica exatamente o que você está procurando: [Angular Router](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)

Answer (score -1):

Passando pelo data eu não aprendi ainda, eu sei fazer desse jeito:

```js
{ path: 'artigo/edit/:id', component: RhFormArtigoComponent},
{ path: 'artigo/edit/:setor/:id', component: RhFormArtigoComponent},
```

No componente recebe assim:

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) { }

this.id_setor = this.route.snapshot.params.setor;
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
```

Comment: No caso eu não gostaria de deixar esses dados no link, eu fiz de uma forma um pouco diferente, mas obrigado de qualquer forma

Comment: Qual foi a forma que você fez? @VeroneseComS

Comment: adicionei uma resposta com a forma que eu resolvi